# "Home Directory / Not Ours" on boot

Tags: debian, gnome, boot, gdm3

I get the line `Home Directory / Not Ours` repeated about 30 times when i boot Debian.

This has recently started happening since i did an update where everything was stuffed up. eg. Gnome and gdm3 uninstalled and a whole lot of other things.

is the best thing to do to reinstall Debian?

Help Needed.

PS. Would like not to reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the ownership or permissions of your home directory has changed.

To fix it, run as root

```
chown -R USER:USER ~USER
chmod u+rwx ~USER
```

where you need to replace `USER` with your username.